# Radio foundation

Tags: forms, button, radio-button, zurb-foundation

I have a problem with the form ZURB foundation. Indeed, the form appears correctly but I can not select.

Here is my code:
You can see that in the first form, the radio works, but the second don't work.

I try many things to resolve this problem but I don't understand where is the problem.

```
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/foundation.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/normalize.css"/>
        <script src="../js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">  
            <form class="custom">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                        <label for="radio1"><input name="radio1" type="radio" id="radio1" style="display:none;" CHECKED><span class="custom radio checked"></span> Radio Button 1</label>
                        <label for="radio1"><input name="radio1" type="radio" id="radio1" style="display:none;"><span class="custom radio"></span> Radio Button 2</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="section-container auto" data-section>
                <section>
                    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel1">Section 1</a></p>
                    <div class="content" data-section-content>
                        <form class="custom">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="large-4 columns">
                                    <label for="radio2"><input name="radio2" type="radio" id="radio2" style="display:none;" CHECKED><span class="custom radio checked"></span> Radio Button 1</label>
                                    <label for="radio2"><input name="radio2" type="radio" id="radio2" style="display:none;"><span class="custom radio"></span> Radio Button 2</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section>
                    <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#panel2">Section 2</a></p>
                    <div class="content" data-section-content>
                       <p>section2</p>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="../js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/foundation/foundation.forms.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/foundation/foundation.section.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/vendor/zepto.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).foundation();

        </script>
   <body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a single id multiple times. It's probably that.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `id` only to the button you want to be selected or use diffeent id's for each option:

Like:

```
<form class="custom">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                        <label for="radio1"><input name="radio1" type="radio" id="CustomFormRadio1" style="display:none;" CHECKED><span class="custom radio checked"></span> Radio Button 1</label>
                        <label for="radio1"><input name="radio1" type="radio" id="CustomFormRadio2" style="display:none;"><span class="custom radio"></span> Radio Button 2</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Or (assuming you want the first that you want to be selected):

```
<form class="custom">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                        <label for="radio1"><input name="radio1" type="radio" id="radio1" style="display:none;" CHECKED><span class="custom radio checked"></span> Radio Button 1</label>
                        <label for="radio1"><input name="radio1" type="radio" style="display:none;"><span class="custom radio"></span> Radio Button 2</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

And then you can do whatever you want with it using `javaScript` with `jQuery`, for example:

```
if($('#CustomFormRadio1').is(':checked')){ 
      //whatever you want here
}
```